# PHPMailer not working - no specific error

Tags: php, email, phpmailer

I have an old website that was not created by me, I noticed that the contact form doesn't work and when you press send it doesn't do anything.
In the console it says:

> POST *path of the mailer file* 500 (Internal Server Error)

I can't find a solution so if anyone can help I would be very grateful.
Here's the code:

```
<?php
require ('libphp-phpmailer/PHPMailerAutoload.php');
$firstname = $_POST['firstname'];
$lastname = $_POST['lastname'];
$email = $_POST['email'];
$phone = $_POST['phone'];
$experience = $_POST['experience'];
$note = $_POST['note'];
$cv = $_POST['cv'];
$sended = 0;
if($firstname != '' && $lastname != '' && $email != '' && $phone != '' && $experience != '' && $note != '' && $cv != ''){
    switch($experience){
        case "1-5":
            $exp = "1 to 5 years";
            break;
        case "5-more":
            $exp = "more than 5 years";
            break;
        default:
            $exp = "nothing";
            break;
    }
    $body = "firstname: " . ucfirst($firstname) . "\n" . "lastname: " . ucfirst($lastname) . "\n" . "phone: " . $phone . "\n" . "Experience: " . $exp . "\n" . $note . "\n\n";
    $mailer = new PHPMailer();
    $mailer->IsSMTP();
    $mailer->Host = '---the email host----';
    $mailer->SMTPAuth = true;
    $mailer->Username = '---the right email---';
    $mailer->Password = '---email password---';
    $mailer->Port = 25;
    $mailer->Encoding = "base64";
    $mailer->CharSet = 'UTF-8';
    $mailer->AuthType = 'PLAIN';
    $mailer->setFrom($email, ucfirst($firstname) . ' ' . ucfirst($lastname));
    $mailer->AddReplyTo($email, ucfirst($firstname) . ' ' . ucfirst($lastname));
    $mailer->AddAddress('---the receiving address---');
    $mailer->isHTML(false);
    $mailer->ContentType = 'text/plain';
    $mailer->Subject = 'Contact form';
    $mailer->Body = $body;
    $mailer->AddAttachment($cv , 'Cv-' . $firstname . '-' . $lastname . '.pdf');
    if($mailer->Send()){
        $sended = 1;
    }
    $response = array(
        'sended'    => $sended
    );
    echo json_encode($response);
}
?>
```

Comment: Add `ini_set("display_errors", "On");` to the top of the file, then add `$mailer->SMTPDebug = 2;` after `$mailer = new PHPMailer();`, and then check the errors that are displayed

Comment: I am unable to see the error in your comment. Please post it in your question

Comment: i did the edit, I am searching the file "working-form.js" I will soon post its contents

Comment: Where did the above error occur? I did not ask you to show the error in the console. I asked you to show the error in the body of the response of the `POST mailer_file ...` request

Comment: I'm sorry but I don't have any other error in my page so I tought you meant the console one

Comment: Press F12, Go to "Network" tab, and click on that request.... It is too hard to guide you in this current situation.

Comment: The error is that the file PHPMailerAutoload doesn't exist... Thank you for your time I didn't know where to check for this error.

Comment: Your problem is solved or not?

Comment: Yes I solved my problem by importing different PHPMailer files

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I added `ini_set("display_errors", "On");` at the top of the file and `mailer->SMTPDebug = 2;` after `$mailer = new PHPMailer();` then I looked at the error in the Network section of the browser toolbox.
I found out that the error was in the line:

```
require ('libphp-phpmailer/PHPMailerAutoload.php');
```

Because PHPMailerAutoload didn't exist so I deleted the line and I uploaded the PHPMailer files (downloaded [here](https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer)) in my website via FTP, then I added these lines at the beginning of my code:

```
use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\PHPMailer;
use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\Exception;
use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\SMTP;

require 'PHPMailer/src/Exception.php';
require 'PHPMailer/src/PHPMailer.php';
require 'PHPMailer/src/SMTP.php';
```

Comment: Thanks the above code worked, but the use statements needed to be placed after the require statements, else it seems to jam up.